# iPhone how to make progress bar clickable like a button?

Tags: iphone, button, progress-bar

I am currently building an iphone game, that when the progress bar is full(that is when the character is in full power), user can click the progress bar and it triggers some action.

How to make a progress bar clickable like a uibutton? I saw the accessibility with the button option, but I have no idea how you implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it or put it inside a `UIButton` with type `UIButtonTypeCustom`